# Custom Button not displaying in 'Recently Viewed'

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-button, list-view

I have a custom list button, using vf page. This button is not visible in 'Recently Viewed' list view of a custom object. But it is visible to anyother list views.

I dont seem to understand the problem.

Earlier it was visible on the 'Recently Viewed' as well. But all of a sudden it was removed from that even if there was no changes made.

Any fix for this?

Comment: Check whether respective button is checked in Search Layout of that object

Comment: Check this Idea link and vote (https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tto8QAC)

Comment: @prathyusha i have already added the button in search layout. and it was showing earlier. suddenly its not visible.

Comment: @SmrutiRanjanBiswal check whether Your profile have access to that component and even to the data in the component